# If the python interpreter is searched by PyCharm itself?

Tags: pycharm

When I set the python interpreter in PyCharm, there will list several python interpreters.

[image]

So, if the PyCharm searched the whole computer when set the Python interpreter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,

from the community version source code https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/172.3652/python/python-community-configure/src/com/jetbrains/python/configuration/PyConfigurableInterpreterList.java#L79-L90

It will search all possible sdk homes, and add detected sdk if it exists.

```
for (String sdkHome : SdkConfigurationUtil.filterExistingPaths(PythonSdkType.getInstance(), sdkHomes, getModel().getSdks())) {
  result.add(new PyDetectedSdk(sdkHome));
}
```